# Reactjs Draw Multiple bounding rectangle box in single image

Tags: reactjs, json, bounding-box

I'm using svg's  tag to draw bbox on image. i can able to draw one rectangle in image. if the json comes with one image with multiple bbox value it still draw one rectangle at the image. then it draws second rectangle to the image as new image it duplicates the image and redraw the second rectangle only.

React code:

```
{this.state.books.map((object) => (
              <div class="img-overlay-wrap"style={{ marginLeft: "27%" }}>
     
              <img  src={`data:image/png;base64,${object.image_id}`} style={{ height:`${object.hw[0]}` , width:`${object.hw[1]}`}} alt="" />
              
              <svg  width={object.hw[1]} height={object.hw[0]} >
              
             <g >
               <rect  x={object.bbox[0]} y={object.bbox[1] - object.bbox[3]}  width={object.bbox[2]} height={object.bbox[3] }
             style={{stroke:"red",}} fill-opacity="0.0" />
                         <text x={object.bbox[0]} y={object.bbox[1]} font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="red">{object.category_id}</text>
             </g>
               
               Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
                  </svg> 
               
                  <h3>Confidence:{object.score}</h3>
                  <h3>Category Id:{object.category_id}</h3>
              
  </div>
            ))}
```

JSON:

```
[
{"image_id":"imageurl",
"bbox": [[406, 417, 115, 210], [187, 420, 89, 189], [275, 424, 95, 272], [272, 133, 34, 22]], 
"score": [0.94813, 0.94638, 0.94348, 0.90018]
}
]
```

In that above json case the number of rectangle is 4(as you see in bbox) but it didn't return all box in single image it only draw image one by one. please tell me how to iterate image and boxes properply.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your rendering code matches up with your json data.